# How to get channel field data from a given entry id?

Tags: custom-fields

I want to get the channel field data from entry id in my custom module.
Is there any way to get the field data.
If anyone knows, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. you can open file *expressionengine/modules/channel/mod.channel.php* and check *function entries()*
2. you can use [Channel-Data](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Channel-Data) lib from Justin Kimbrell to simplify access to  channel data.

*example*

```
    $entries = $this->EE->channel_data->get_channel_entries($channel_id, array(
        'select'    => array('*'),
        'where'     => array('channel_data.entry_id >' => 1),
        'order_by'  => 'title',
        'sort'      => 'ASC',
        'limit'     => 1,
        'offset'    => 5
    ));
```

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with few instructions - how to install Channel-Data. Where to put these files?